# What's a robust method in R for importing from and exporting data to Excel?

Tags: r, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

I've used RODBC for some time to import Excel spreadsheets with mostly good results. However I have had no luck writing to an Excel spreadsheet. Also are there favorable differences using the xlsx format with Excel2007?

Answer (score 6):

I've used the technique described here: [Export Data Frames To Multi-worksheet Excel File](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/export-data-frames-to-multi-worksheet-excel-file/)

Answer (score 3):

The [R Data Import/Export manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html) should be considered the best source of advice for these questions.

For *reading* you can indeed use the [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) package.  An easier solutoion may be `read.xls()` from the [gdata](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/index.html)

For *writing* you can use one of the wrapper packages such as [WriteXLS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WriteXLS/index.html) which wraps around Perl libraries that know how to write in the proprietary and not formally documented xls format.

In general, xlsx will *not* be a solution as this format is newer, once again proprietary and not documented.  For that reason there are even fewer tools coping with this.

Comment: xlsx is an open format (though probably complicated) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181.aspx
You can actually unzip an xlsx file and view the xml. I expect this will result eventually in a good read/write solution.

Comment: I see. Well, so you have the need for a new `write.xlsx()` function, and the know-how.  So go off now and scratch that itch :)

Comment: The manual leaves out something pretty important: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script/26265428#26265428

Answer (score 3):

`XLConnect` works well. It is cross-platform. It can read and write xls and xlsx files. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6100369/180892)

Answer (score 2):

This question is 3 years old, but I'll throw this in: if you want to write to the spreadsheet, remember to add `readOnly=FALSE` as an argument to `odbcConnectExcel` and `odbcConnectExcel2007`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that may help with dealing with excel 2007, but I haven't tried it.

http://www.omegahat.org/RExcelXML/