# How to read Excel into R and execute hurst(x)?

Tags: r

I never used R before and so need help on a seemingly trivial issue:

I have an excel file "data.xlsx", available [here](http://www.filedropper.com/data_4), and want to run the function `hurst(x)` on it: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pracma/docs/hurst

I did:

```
theData <- readWorksheetFromFile("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\R\\data.xlsx",sheet=1)
```

Which works fine. Then I try

```
library(pracma)
hurst(theData)
```

Which returns

```
   Error: could not find function "hurst"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `install.packages("pracma"); library("pracma")`; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049272/importing-xlsx-file-into-r ; `hurst(imported_data[[1]])`; and then edit your question to let us know what you're still stuck on (it may well be closed in the meanwhile ...)

Comment: A Google search should have turned up [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf), among several other packages for importing Excel files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the link you gave points to an old version of the package; the `hurst` function no longer exists in the package.  The current documentation is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf); try

```
library("gdata")  ## my favorite XLS-reader
x <- read.xls("hurstdata.xlsx",header=FALSE)
hurstexp(x[[1]])
## Simple R/S Hurst estimation:         0.5488892 
## Corrected R over S Hurst exponent:   0.6172157 
## Empirical Hurst exponent:            0.6796684 
## Corrected empirical Hurst exponent:  0.6438013 
## Theoretical Hurst exponent:          0.5316731
```

Abridged session information:

```
R Under development (unstable) (2014-09-17 r66626)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

other attached packages:
[1] pracma_1.7.9 gdata_2.13.3
```

Comment: It gives "Error in matrix(x, n, m) : invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)"? However, "> sum(theData[[1]])
[1] -59.86539" works

Comment: I think we need a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) please ...

Comment: I uploaded the Excel file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/data_4). I want to call "hurstexp(x)" with this data...