# Readin .xlsx file into R

Tags: r

Im trying to read an excel file into R. It's about the following file in my cwd:

```
 > list.files()
 [1] "Keuren_Op_Afspraak.xlsx"
```

I installed XLConnect and am doing the following:

```
library(XLConnect)
demoExcelFile <- system.file("Keuren_Op_Afspraak.xlsx", package = "XLConnect")
wb <- loadWorkbook(demoExcelFile)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Error: FileNotFoundException (Java): File '' could not be found - you may specify to automatically create the file if not existing.
```

But I dont understand where this is coming from. Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing .xlsx file into R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049272/importing-xlsx-file-into-r)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using the readxl package.  It is written in C so it is faster.  It also seems to handle large files better.  The command would be:

```
library(readxl)
wb <- read_excel("Keuren_Op_Afspraak.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the xlsx package.

```
library(xlsx)
wb <- read.xlsx("Keuren_Op_Afspraak.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

Edit :@Verena

You can also use this function much faster:

```
wb <- read.xlsx2("Keuren_Op_Afspraak.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

Comment: From this package I would use read.xlsx2("Keuren_Op_Afspraak.xlsx", sheet=1) it is a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code that way:

```
library(XLConnect)
demoExcelFile <- "Keuren_Op_Afspraak.xlsx"
wb <- loadWorkbook(demoExcelFile)
```

You probably took the example from here:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/XLConnect/docs/loadWorkbook

This line

```
system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", package = "XLConnect")
```

is a way to get sample files that are part of a package. If you download the zip File of XLConnect and look into the folder structure you will see that there is a folder demoFiles that contains mtcars.xlsx. And the parameter package="XLConnect" tells the method to look for the file in this package.

If you type it into the command line it returns the absolute path to the file:

```
"C:/Users/Expecto/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/XLConnect/demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx"
```

To use loadWorkbook you simply need to pass the relative or absolute filepath.

Comment: @ExpectoPartonum, thanks. I already tried this but then I get a memory error: Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: How large is your file?

Comment: @MarcvanderPeet maybe you need to increase your heap: options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m") (insert any number that suits you but of course you have to take care how much memory your machine has)

Comment: @MarcvanderPeet You could also try to load each sheet separately (if you have more than one)