# Sorting and rearranging Excel datatable in R

Tags: r, excel

I have an Excel file with data (5 columns and 200 rows).

Rows are the next:

`TransactionId`, `UserId`, `transaction_date`, `transaction_status`, `amount_USD`.

The data.table is like that (it is not full, just to catch the idea):

Screenshot of datatable1

[image]

The task is rearrange the table in way it will look like 3 columns (transaction_date, CHARGED, DECLINED), where CHARGED and DECKLINED - are the sum of all amount_USD by the same date with specific status (Charged or Declined).

So, it should look like that:

[image]

And also, when I use such code for importing from Excel - is it correct?

```
> library("xlsx")

> data1 <- read.xlsx("d:/R/1.xlsx", 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: If you're able to read in the data from Excel then paste a representation sample of the data using `dput` and we can help you rearrange it. If you can't import the data from Excel then focus on that problem first and let us know what error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to group by date and transaction type (Charged/Declined).

I'm not sure if you were planning to use *R* for a specific reason, so I'll show you one way to do it in *R* and also how to do it in Excel, in case you want to save yourself some effort.

- **Using R**

If you plan to use R for this task, you may want to save the current Excel file 'filename.xlsx' as 'filename.csv' because R requires some additional libraries to read in Excel native files. They've never worked for me, so I just use .csv files instead.
The dummy_csv file I created is formatted like yours, so just change the code as necessary:

```
> dummy_csv
  transaction_ID      Date Transaction_type    Amount
1            101 12.1.2016          Charged  $270.29 
2            102  1.6.2015         Declined  $840.25 
3            103 12.1.2016          Charged  $233.26 
4            104  1.7.2016         Declined  $406.04 
5            105  1.7.2016          Charged  $886.73 
6            106 12.1.2016         Declined  $348.44 
7            107  3.8.1015          Charged  $430.09 
8            108  3.7.2015         Declined  $655.17
```

Here's the code:

```
install.packages('dplyr') # Install dplyr if you don't have it.
library(dplyr) # Load dplyr


dummy_csv <- read.csv("~/dummy_csv.csv") # Import dataset 

dummy_csv <- tbl_df(dummy_csv) # Convert to table dataframe via dplyr

dummy_csv$Amount <- sub(pattern = "$", # Get rid of dollar signs
                    replacement = "",
                    x=as.character(dummy_csv$Amount),
                    fixed=TRUE)

dummy_csv <- mutate(dummy_csv,Amount = as.numeric(Amount)) # Make the values numeric

dummy_csv <- dummy_csv %>%
            group_by(Date,Transaction_type) %>%
            summarise('Daily_Total' = sum(Amount))
```

The output in R will be:

```
       Date Transaction_type Daily_Total
 (fctr)           (fctr)       (dbl)
1  1.6.2015         Declined      840.25
2  1.7.2016          Charged      886.73
3  1.7.2016         Declined      406.04
4 12.1.2016          Charged      503.55
5 12.1.2016         Declined      348.44
6  3.7.2015         Declined      655.17
7  3.8.1015          Charged      430.09
```

- **Using Excel**

You can accomplish the same task in Excel without using R.

1. Highlight the range of data in Excel and click on the Insert menu -> pivot table.
2. In the Pivot Table dialogue box, Drag 'Date' and 'Transaction_Type' into the Rows box.  Drag 'Amount' into the Values box, and set the calculation as SUM().

The output will be the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! The code seems to be ok, hope the task will be ok too. And yep, the variant with Excel is much better, but the task was exactly in R =(

Answer (score 0):

These questions have been answered before. Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049272/importing-xlsx-file-into-r) I found in 2 seconds regarding issues with reading .xlsx files into R.

I recommend saving the xlsx file as a .csv and using `read.csv`. Read the file in like this:

```
data1 <- read.csv("d:/R/1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

R is not going to recognize the appropriate formats for your date and USD columns. You can make sure to change your USD column by having `.` instead of `,`.

Here is what you want to accomplish using [reshape()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r) with sample data since you did not provide any in R.

```
data1 <- data.frame(
  date=c("22.08.2015","11.08.2015","24.08.2015","28.07.2015"),
  transaction_status=c("CHARGED","DECLINED","CHARGED","DECLINED"),
  amount=c(10.96,14.7,10.61,10.96)
)

#convert your date from character to date
data1$date <- as.Date(data1$date, "%d.%m.%Y") 

#put your data in wide format
data1 <- reshape(data1, idvar="date", timevar="transaction_status", direction="wide")

#sort by date
data1 <- data1[order(data1$date),]
```

Is this output what you are looking for?

```
> data1
        date amount.CHARGED amount.DECLINED
4 2015-07-28             NA           10.96
2 2015-08-11             NA           14.70
1 2015-08-22          10.96              NA
3 2015-08-24          10.61              NA
```

Comment: Thank you! The screenshot I provided is not the whole data table... The whole is 200 rows. Am i right that your method is mile manual creating a table? And what about outcome - that looks correct. =)

Comment: @P.Dan I'm not sure if I understand your question. The data I created was just an example with 3 columns and 4 rows. One thing I should add is that since you have those two other columns you'll want to set `idvar=c("TransactionId","UserId","transaction_date")` when you use `reshape` . If I answered your question adequately please check it :)

Comment: Sorry it was missprint ("mile"="like"). I really don't understand this step : "data1 <- data.frame(...." - is this one creation of your own sample? I mean, when I import .csv - it is NOT data.frame from the beginning, should I convert imported .csv to data.frame or smth? Because when I tried without this step it writes me that it doesn't know how to convert "data$transaction_date" to class "date"...