# R: how to import a few non-contiguous columns using readxl?

Tags: r, readxl

I only want to import columns 1, 2, 4, 5 of my .xlsx file, so I tried:

```r
read_xlsx(path, range=cell_cols(c(1, 2, 4, 5))
```

However, this imports all columns from column 1 to 5 (i.e. columns 1, 2, **3**, 4, 5). Not what I want.

I cannot find the right way to do this using `readxl`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: From the documentation for `cell_cols()`: Note it is not possible to request non-contiguous columns, i.e. columns 1, 2, and 5. In this case, the requested columns will run from the minimum of 1 to the maximum of 5.   ....  If you want to use `readxl()` you'll need to read the entire range in and subset after.

Comment: Been looking into this today and also found no joy with readxl and subsetting after you read it in seems to be the only option: `my_data <- read_xlsx(path)[, c(1, 2, 4, 5)]`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to skip a column, I suggest using the `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` for reading. It contains a `rows` and a `cols` argument, with whom you can control what rows/columns to read.

sample excel:

[image]

code:

```
library(openxlsx)
openxlsx::read.xlsx("./data/test_excel.xlsx", cols = c(1:3, 5:6))
#   a b c e f
# 1 1 2 3 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, openxlsx is slower and I have many files to import.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538199/fast-way-to-read-xlsx-files-into-r