# Coercing R to use HDD drives in addition to CPU RAM

Tags: r, memory

I am developing an app which will run locally on a VM with 128GB RAM and is set up as a project in R Studio. It will just about run with the most complex combination of possible user inputs, but is painfully slow. The tasks it performs are ETL from large excel sheets, dplyr and datatable based data restructuring and calculations, and outputting graphs and tables to a Shiny UI. I realise that a cloud solution would be better, but we are tied to this setup for various reasons.

We are prevented from adding additional RAM but the machine has 2x 1TB HDD (D and E) drives which are empty. At the moment the app is causing R to work right up to the limit of the CPU memory. I'd like to force R to access the D and E drive storage when it hits the CPU limit and use that extra capacity as working memory, but I can't seem to enable this. Does anyone know if this is possible? We are currently using a Windows environment but could switch to linux or Mac if this allowed us to solve the issue.

Things I have tried so far- increasing page sizing for the D and E drives in the systems settings to set up space swapping, and setting invisible(utils::memory.limit(n)) in the .RProfile file. This second approach fails as memory.limit is now deprecated. Memory.limit() returns Inf but this refers only to the CPU. I expected to be able to enable additional working memory, but R is still only utilising CPU RAM.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Take a look at the `ff` package if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm looking into ff and Bigmemory but will still need to read in the large xlsm input files to convert them to csv as neither support xlsm format. To give more information, I am working with xlsm workbooks which a team updates weekly in Dropbox. Migrating to google cloud or AWS would be my preference but this has been ruled out.

Comment: Without knowing how the data are being used or the number and size of the files, my first thought is to use `readxl` or `openxlsx` (depending on file sizes and memory, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706335/9463489)), then immediately do `data.table::setDT` and write to disk with the `fst` package. The data can then be read into and removed from RAM as needed. `fst` files are compressed by default, have very fast read/write speeds, and offer subsettable reads (both row and column).

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at fst that is extremely helpful! I am currently reading in excel sheets then saving them as rds but if there is a more compact format that would be good.

Comment: On second thought, no need to do `setDT` unless you want to set a key. You can read in the .fst as a `data.table` using the `as.data.table` argument of `read.fst`.