# Error: could not find function "read_excel" using R on Mac

Tags: r, macos, readxl

I am trying to link up my excel data set to R for statistical analysis. I am running on OSX Sierra (10.12.6) with R studio (1.0.153) and Java 8 (update 144).

The function "read_excel" was able to open my excel document a week ago. When I moved the excel and the R document together to another folder, it no longer worked. Reloading the libraries has had no effect. After multiple attempts (and restarting R studio and computer), something finally worked but function "lmer" was no longer found. After reloading library "lme4", "read_excel" no longer worked!

I have also tried using "read.xlsx" and "readWorksheet(loadWorkbook(...))", which didn't work. "read.csv" also did not work properly since the commas were creating disorganized columns and I am dealing with a larger excel workbook with ongoing changes.

Reading on Stack, question [Importing .xlsx file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049272/importing-xlsx-file-into-r) has not resolved my issue! Please help!

Libraries loaded:

```
library(multcomp)
library(nlme)
library(XLConnect)
library(XLConnectJars)
library(lme4)
library(car)
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)
library(readxl)
```

R data file:

```
Dataset <- read_excel("Example.xlsx",sheet="testing")
#alternative line: Dataset <- read.xlsx("~/Desktop/My Stuff/Sample/Example.xlsx", sheet=7)

Dataset$AAA <- as.factor(Dataset$AAA)
Dataset$BBB <- as.factor(Dataset$BBB)
Dataset$CCC <- as.numeric(Dataset$CCC)
Dataset$DDD <- as.numeric(Dataset$DDD)

Dataset_lme = lmer(CCC ~ AAA + BBB + (1|DDD), data=Dataset)
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages you are seeing and where exactly do they occur? Try running your script one line at a time to verify.

Comment: > at this point it doesn't run past the first line 
    "Dataset <- read_excel("Example.xlsx", sheet = "testing")
Error in read_excel("Example.xlsx", sheet = "testing") : 
  could not find function "read_excel""

Comment: Well, if you ran `library(readxl)` prior to that, that seems very odd. Did you get an error when running `library(readxl)`? After you run it does "package:readxl" show up in `search()`?

Comment: after I installed the library it shows that it's downloaded, but when I use the search() function, none of my loaded libraries show up. This is what I get:

 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 [5] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
 [9] "Autoloads"         "package:base"

Comment: Well, installing isn't the same as loading. You only install once, but you need to load at the beginning of each R session. Did you actually run `library(readxl)` in the console to load the installed package? You have that command listed above so I assumed you ran it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you called the library, try and see if adding readxl::read_excel(path = "yourPath",sheet=1), or even remove the sheet reference.  It will automatically take the first sheet.

Comment: Thanks Carl! This allowed the script to run past the first line! What you've added, is this just a way to specify what library to look for the function? It still doesn't run past the "lmer" function in the script (error = not finding the function).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, when you moved the excel and R file to another folder, the pathway should be change either.
Try change the pathway, or replace the pathay by `file.choose()` and search the excel file manually.
You called the package "xlsx", which can do the thing what you need. Maybe you're typing it wrong.

```
Dataset <- read.xlsx("Example.xlsx",sheetName="testing")
```

or

```
Dataset <- read.xlsx("Example.xlsx",sheetIndex="number of the excel sheet")
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try activating `library(tidyverse)` and `library(readr)` then use the `read_excel()`. This should work.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.