# MemoryError in R while read.xlsx

Tags: java, r, out-of-memory, heap-memory, r-xlsx

I am using the following R code (that utilizes the Java parameter to increase memory as well):

```
library(xlsx)
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1g")
library(XLConnect)
NiVe <- read.xlsx("version1.xlsx",1)
```

The `version1.xlsx` file is 13 MB in size. I get the following error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Can someone help?

Comment: It's because of this issue that I gave up on the `xlsx` package and have moved to `readxl`, which is [faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script/31734198#31734198)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I recently encountered the same problem with the xlsx package. I normally use the readxl package for reading Excel files, but had to use the xlsx package as readxl can't open password-protected spreadsheets.

Answer (score 19):

Try to increase java Heap size(sufficient), by using:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
```

> If you are using 32 bit R make sure you are also using 32 bit Java and
>   if you re using 64 bit R make sure you are also using 64 bit Java. If
>   you get a Java heap space message indicating that it is out of memory
>   see [this post](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows#exchanging_data_between_r_and_ms_windows_apps_excel_etc).

[this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.mac/6552) may help you, to use Garbage Collection.

**Reference:**
[exchanging_data_between_r_and_ms_windows_apps_excel_etc](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows#exchanging_data_between_r_and_ms_windows_apps_excel_etc)
[stats-rosuda-devel_001621](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/pipermail/stats-rosuda-devel/2011q1/001621.html)

Comment: `If you are using 32 bit R make sure you are also using 32 bit Java and if you re using 64 bit R make sure you are also using 64 bit Java`. How does one check this?

Answer (score 7):

You should make sure that you are setting the Java parameters **before** any JVM is initialized, i.e. before either the XLConnect or xlsx packages are loaded. Note that in your case you are using the *read.xlsx* function which is not an XLConnect function and therefore the XLConnect package is not required. The XLConnect alternative is the function *readWorksheetFromFile*.

Comment: Any idea why it takes so much memory to open an Excel file? I had to set my limit to 2 GB to open a 23 MB file.

Comment: I'm with @rrs, just had Java freak out after being given 25GB memory to write 15MB file....

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-
May be this can work. It worked for me

1)  when downloading the xlsx file, use this 
download.file(fileURL, destfile="./whatever", mode="wb")

2)  Switched to regular R, not R Studio,