# Write data into a specific workbook sheet

Tags: r, excel

I have a data frame e.g.

```
a=1:10 
b=31:40
c=data.frame(a=a,b=b)
```

and I will need to write this data frame into a specific Excel sheet ("Sheet1").

I am using WriteXLS now but this function always overrides the entire excel file and thus deletes other sheets.
How can I append to the sheet without overwriting previous entries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read an Excel file directly from a R script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script)

Comment: The above-linked question is technically about reading, not writing, Excel files, but the tools used are the same.

Comment: i have no problem reading from a specific sheet and writing to excel. But writing to a specific sheet in excel is puzzling me.

Comment: `writeWorksheet` in the `XLConnect` package sounds like it'll do the trick

Comment: Which is precisely why I pointed you towards the tools that allow you to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This will add a new named sheet to an existing Excel workbook without altering existing sheets:

```
# create data in R
a = 1:10 
b = 31:40
c0 = data.frame(a=a,b=b)

#  write data object 'c0' to existing Excel file 
# 'Book1.xlsx' into a new sheet called 'Sheet1'
library(XLConnect)
writeWorksheetToFile(file = "C:/.../Book1.xlsx", data = c0, sheet = "Sheet1")
```

Note that if the workbook already has a `Sheet1` then this function would silently overwrite it. So you'll need to make sure your sheet names are unique.

Answer (score 2):

Try with xlsx package. You have the function write.xlsx() which allows you to specify a name sheet and you can complete an existing excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write into a new sheet of an existing Excel file without modifiying the existing sheets or any other information by doing it this way:

```
library(xlsx)
a=1:10 
b=31:40
c=data.frame(a=a,b=b)

write.xlsx(c, "existing_Excel_file.xlsx", sheetName="New sheet name",  append=TRUE)
```

Remember to set the **append** argument of write.xlsx to **TRUE** and make sure the Excel file you are writing in to is in your current working Directory.