# How to append different R outputs into one excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, excel, append

So whenever I want to run my code seperately for different datasets...I want the output from my code to be saved in the same excel spreadsheet but at different sheets....So If I run my code for 20 different datasets...I would want all the output to saved in the same excel spreadsheet but different worksheets...so I would have 20 worksheets in a single excel spreadsheet...is there a special function in r that would let me do this?.....so lets say my existing spreadsheet is called 'Values.csv'....How would I append the rest of my output to this same spreadsheet.

I usually just use `write.csv(data,'Values.csv')` etc....But I'm not sure how to append my output to this same worksheet...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15151255/1036500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use library `XLConnect` to do this.

```
library(XLConnect)

#some sample data
your.data=data.frame(a=1:10,b=21:30)

#Create .xls file
wb <- loadWorkbook("newfile.xls", create = TRUE)

#Create Sheet in file
createSheet(wb,name="name_one")

#write data
writeWorksheet(wb,your.data,sheet="name_one")

#save .xls file
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: Do you know any similar package for ODF spreadsheets?

Comment: @TheodoreLytras Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I'm having  trouble because I have the R version 2.15.2 and I cant install XLConnect properly...but I think your code would work so well for me

Comment: Would there be another way to do it?...I was able to download XLConnect properly but now I'm having trouble downloading rJava