# Import an *.xls file in R?

Tags: windows, r

I am struggeling to read an *.xls file into R:

I did the following:

I set my working directory to the *.xls file and then:

```
> library(gdata)                   # load the gdata package 
> mydata = read.xls("comprice.xls", sheet=1, verbose=FALSE) 
Mistake in findPerl(verbose = verbose) :  perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path. mistake in file.exists(tfn) : unknown 'file' argument
```

However, my path is correct and there is the file! Whats wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have installed it already, however now I get: Exception: cannot find function "read.xls"...

Comment: Is Perl already installed on your computer? Seems like `gdata` can't find it.

Comment: I have installed it already, however now I get: Exception: cannot find function "read.xls"...

Comment: Can you save yourself a whole lot of bother and export to csv?

Comment: @maximus Try to close existing R session, star new R session and see if the error message still appears.

Comment: @alexwhan And click "yes" twice to "are you sure that want to save this document in this weird format?" popups every time you edit the file with Excel? `xlsx` package is a really an excellent shortcut for those who like to edit their data with Excel, but hate that damn saving process

Comment: Ivve never understood how two clicks of the mouse (or a quick double tap of enter) is worth all the pain of having your data in a proprietary format... But each to their own!

Comment: There are a bunch of other methods for this here: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message means that perl is not installed on your computer or it is not set on your path.

If the perl is installed then you can put argument `perl=` inside  `read.xls()` function.

```
read.xls(xlsfile, perl="C:/perl/bin/perl.exe")
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could try `xlsx`package:

`read.xlsx("comprice.xls", 1)` reads your file and makes the data.frame column classes nearly useful, *but* is very slow for large data sets.

`read.xlsx2("comprice.xls", 1)` is faster, but you'll have to define column classes manually. If you run the command twice, you will not need to count columns so much:

```
data <- read.xlsx2("comprice.xls", 1)    
data <- read.xlsx2("comprice.xls", 1, colClasses= rep("numeric", ncol(data)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl is either not installed or cannot be found. You can either install it, or specify the path where it is installed using

```
perl='path of perl installation'
```

in the call.