# read.xlsx() one row each time keeps getting OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, r, out-of-memory, heap-memory, r-xlsx

I am new to R and want to import an Excel file into SQL Server.
Each time,read 1 row and insert 1 row using sqlQuery(as I worry about some big excel sheet in the future).
Only after 7 rows inserted and the error pops up and keeps coming during later re-runs(increased the Jave memory to 2G but no difference).

Is there somebody know this and please kindly point out the problem with my coding style or synatax?
Much appreciate for your reply:)

```
 > library(xlsx)
 Loading required package: xlsxjars
 Loading required package: rJava
 > .jinit(parameters="-Xmx2g")
 [1] 0
 > for(i in 1:100 ){
 + Res <- read.xlsx(file="D:/mingdong/R/SECM.xlsx",sheetIndex=1,startRow=i, endRow=i+1,colIndex =1:4,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,encoding="UTF-8")
 + print(paste(Res)) }
 [1] "000000" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 [1] "000001" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 [1] "000002" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 [1] "000003" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 [1] "000004" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 [1] "000005" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 [1] "000006" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 [1] "000007" "1"      "A360"   "1000"  
 Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 >
```

Comment: Why are you reading only two rows at a time using file access. Why not read the whole spreadsheet at once?

Comment: Sometimes the excel file maybe very large, reading all rows into memory may cause the memory overflow directly, which we must consider it.

Comment: Edited it and simplified it as their is perhaps a little long codes

Comment: Then why not read in 1000 rows at a time and process?

Comment: yeah, I am considering reading 1000 rows a time, but I am afraid after reading 7*1000 rows it will fail as well

Comment: I am considering turning to RODBC.But I dont know how to import 1 or 1000 rows a time in sqlQuery().Could anybody please tell me how to load 1 or 1000 rows a time in RODBC?

Comment: It's because of this issue that I gave up on the `xlsx` package and have moved to `readxl`, which is [faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script/31734198#31734198)