# Write multiple R-summaries to a single excel file

Tags: r

How can I write several summaries to an Excel file, to have:

1. In the first column (Min, 1st Qu, Median, Mean, 3rd Qu, Max), and in the subsequent columns only the numerical values.
2. On the top row I need the name of the variables that I am summarizing.

Comment: There are many options to write to xls(x) files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script The last hot thing is the `openxlsx` package, independent of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess it would be something like

```
df<-data.frame("a"=rnorm(10), "b"=rnorm(10), "c"=rnorm(10))
output<-apply(X=df, MARGIN=2,FUN=summary)
write.table(output, file="output.csv", dec=",", sep=";")
```

depending on your excel version, the 'dec' and 'sep' parameters for export might vary.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `data.frame` with row names "Min", "1st Qu", etc. und column names of your variables and then call the usual export functions such as `write.csv` in base R, `WriteXLS` in the `WriteXLS` package or `write.xlsx` in the `xlsx` package. Be sure to use the `row.names=TRUE` argument.