# Perl not found in gdata package in R

Tags: r, perl, gdata

I get this error while using `read.xls()`,

```
Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

How and where to download perl for gdata package in R?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099308/3710546

Comment: Also there are two newer packages, openxlsx and readxl, which use C++ and so can read Excel spreadsheets without needing perl, java or other separately downloaded dependency.

Answer (score 0):

use below thing to find the perl

1. find the location of perl in the system and specify the exact path

read.xls(verbose=FALSE, perl="C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe")