# Importing excel file in R

Tags: r, xls, data-import

I have an excel file that is stored on http:..../test.xls, how do i import this file into R ?

I tried using the gdata package but it requires Perl and I cannot install Perl on my office machine.

Comment: Try the `readxl` package: https://github.com/hadley/readxl. It has no external dependencies so it's easy to install and use on all operating systems

Comment: A good way is `read.xlsx(file)`using the `xlsx` package. It requires `Java` though. Hope you can install it or have it already on your computer.

Comment: But you may have to download the file first with `download.file` or the RCurl package or httr or something rather than getting it directly from an http:// URL. Or maybe that's handled in the readxl package?

Comment: @Spacedman `readxl` uses `download.file` internally: https://github.com/jentjr/readxl/commit/0fb50846a110d63e53e3537c02fc66c63c71acc6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read an Excel file directly from a R script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `readxl` (installation instruction [here](https://github.com/hadley/readxl#installation))

> The `readxl` package makes it easy to get data out of Excel and into R.
>   Compared to many of the existing packages (e.g. `gdata`, `xlsx`,
>   `xlsReadWrite`) readxl **has no external dependencies** so it's easy to
>   install and use on all operating systems. It is designed to work with
>   tabular data stored in a single sheet.

**Note:** As per mentionned by @Spacedman, you may have to download the file first using `download.file` or your favorite Curl package.

You could also use [jentjr](https://github.com/jentjr/readxl)'s fork which [adds URL capability](https://github.com/jentjr/readxl/commit/0fb50846a110d63e53e3537c02fc66c63c71acc6) to `readxl` by using `download.file` internally:

```
devtools::install_github("jentjr/readxl")
library(readxl)

idem_url <- "http://www.in.gov/idem/files/groundwater_gwmn_data_2008.xls"
gw <- read_excel(idem_url)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you installed R there were several documents that installed with it (one way to see these docs is run the command `help.start()`).  One of these documents is called "R Data Import/Export", section 9 of that document is titled "Reading Excel Spreadsheets" and it gives multiple options along with some discussion of what requirements there are for each.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest library **xlsx**.  Please check method **?read.xlsx**