# Importing dataset from Excel to R - Why are my column titles imported as "double" and not as "character"

Tags: r

I am trying to import a dataset from Excel and all of my titles for the columns in excel are formatted as text. When I import them to R they become doubles and I cant covert the data into longframe because of it. I'm not sure why as I've imported other seemingly identical files wihtout issue but now I cant import anything without half of the names being considered "double" while others are considered "character"

I can only figure out how to change them by manually changing each column to character as I import

Comment: What command do you use to import the data?

Comment: I have tried to both write out the script as "library(readxl)
DW75 <- read_excel("~/Downloads/75dw.xlsx", 
    sheet = "Sheet2")
View(DW75)" as well as using R-studios import from excel function

Comment: you could try manually changing using df$name <- as.character(df$name) or df$name <- as.factor(df$name)

Comment: If there are any letters or non-digit characters in your data, R may interpret that as a character field. You can convert many cols to numeric at once, though, like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772279/converting-multiple-columns-from-character-to-numeric-format-in-r

Comment: did you check to see how those columns or cells (for the headers) are formatted in Excel?

Comment: Also see if this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633891/specifying-column-types-when-importing-xlsx-data-to-r-with-package-readxl/34015430#34015430

Comment: There is a `col_types` argument to `read_excel` where you can specify "text". But it would help to see some data so we can figure out why this is happening.