# R read.xlsx colClasses issue

Tags: r, import-from-excel, r-xlsx

I am having a problem using the `colClasses` function in `read.xlsx`

I have the following `data.frame`

```
mydata <- read.xlsx("dataset_1.xlsx", sheetName = "dataset_1")
head(mydata)
Treatment Nitrate_conc
1         1           12
2         1           12
3         1           15
4         1           16
5         1           12
6         2           18
str(mydata)
data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Treatment   : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Nitrate_conc: num  12 12 15 16 12 18 25 26 28 28 ...
```

I want to import `Treatment` as a `factor`. to do this I have attempted to use the `colClasses` function as an argument as shown below:

```
mydata1 <- read.xlsx("dataset_1.xlsx", sheetName = "dataset_1", colClasses = c("Treatment" = "factor", "Nitrate_conc" = "numeric"))
```

However I get the following error:

> Error in `class(aux) <- colClasses[ic]` : 
>       adding class `factor` to an invalid object

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think it is more `colClasses = c("factor", "numeric")`.

Comment: @Pascal the [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xlsx/docs/read.xlsx) suggest `colClasses` can take a named argument.

Comment: @RoryShaw have you checked `names(mydata)` to be sure there isn't perhaps an errant space? You may also consider using one of the other, [faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script/31734198#31734198) Excel reading options... I personally only use `read.xlsx` when the file has a `Date` in it.

Comment: @MichaelChirico thanks for your help and link to other methods.

Comment: @Pascal pretty certain colClassess can take a named argument - it works with read.csv etc

Comment: @RoryShaw Pretty sure I never used it. But please do so.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but it looks like it was never fully answered.

This has nothing to do with whether or not the elements of the list for `colClasses` is named.  The problem can be traced through the documentation `?read.xlsx` . In describing the `colClasses` parameter, the documentation points to the documentation for `readColumns`.  In the description there, it says

> Only numeric, character, Date, POSIXct, column types are accepted.
>   Anything else will be coverted to a character type.

So specifying `'factor'` is not permitted. Also note that under `...` it says

> other arguments to data.frame, for example stringsAsFactors

So, we can use

```
mydata <- read.xlsx("dataset_1.xlsx", sheetName = "dataset_1", 
  colClasses=c("character", "numeric"))
str(mydata)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Treatment   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 2
 $ Nitrate_conc: num  12 12 15 16 12 18
```

You can also use:

```
mydata <- read.xlsx("dataset_1.xlsx", sheetName = "dataset_1", 
    colClasses=c(Treatment = "character", Nitrate_conc = "numeric"))
```

It looks like there is just one parameter `stringsAsFactors`  so it may not be possible to read both factors and strings at the same time. Of course,  you can always convert a column to a factor after having read it as a different type.