# Open Excel File in R With Only Partially Known File Name

Tags: r, read.table

I would like to open an Excel file in directory "dld" that starts with "RPT". I've tried the below, but I keep getting an error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the code coming from a read.csv and I'm trying to adapt it to read.table.

```
dld <- "C:/Users/Me/Downloads/"
filename <- paste(dld, "RPT_", sep = "")
file <- read.table(dir(dirname(filename), full.names=T, pattern=paste("^", basename(filename), sep="")))
```

Ideas? Any direction/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say Excel file, do you mean .xls or .xlsx? Or do you just mean a .csv that happens to have been saved from Excel?

Comment: @joran .xlsx, thanks!

Comment: In that case you'll want to use a package like **readxl**, **XLConnect** or **xlsx** that are specifically for reading that file format.

Answer (score 1):

First, as @joran mentioned, there are several tools for reading `.xlsx` or `xls` files directly (all of which are covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6099243/3576984)).

As to your question of finding a partially matched file name, I would use `grepl` as follows:

```
#get all file names in the directory
flz <- list.files("C:/Users/Me/Downloads/")
#find those that start with RPT (or otherwise match your pattern)
my_excel <- flz[grepl("^RPT", flz)]
#(make sure here that you've identified a unique file)
```

Finally, read the file:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel(my_excel) #(specifying whichever options as needed)
```

Comment: You may want to consider what to do if there are multiple filenames that start with RPT_.

Comment: @user2747404 that's why I left `my_excel` as its own line instead of combining with `read_excel`. A user should examine `my_excel` before proceeding & decide what adjustments need be made to the regex (if any).