# Why can I not load a .xlsx file in Rstudio?

Tags: r, excel, statistics

I am a beginner and am trying to make some basic graphs for school, and every time I try to load, the following error occurs:

```
load("UmsatzImEinzelhandel_Quartalsdaten.xlsx")
```

> Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   file 'UmsatzImEinzelhandel_Quartalsdaten.xlsx' has magic number 'PK'
>     Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

I need to load a simple data table created in Excel, but it keeps popping this error message. I have tried to even recreate the whole table and it simply does not work. I don't know what I have to do.
Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Look at the `readxl` package for reading in excel data files into R.

Comment: From `?load`: "Reload datasets written with the function save." Excel files are not "written with the function save."

Comment: you can't load excel files this way - have a look here how you manage to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script