# R why i cant use the xlsx library?

Tags: java, r, xlsx

im having some troubles in at work w/ an 32-bit windows 7 version, im on the task to create automatised xls document, for that i installed this 3 packages on R

1. rJava
2. xlsxjars
3. xlsx

all seems to be fine but when i try to call the xlsx i get this

```
    > library(xlsx)
Loading required package: xlsx
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: Cannot create Java virtual machine (-1)
>
```

U.U im getting nuts in this hehehe any advices would be really nice! tank u for reading

Comment: The versions of R and Java must be compatible: if R is 32 bits so must be Java, and if not they must both be 64 bits. In Windows 7 R installs 32 and 64 bits, so maybe all you have to do is to run the right version.

Comment: Try the openxlsx package. It does not run on Java as far as I know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script/

Comment: Or `readxl`. Won't work for Excel output but does a good job reading in Excel files.

Comment: im on 32 wind 7, anyway can i install an 64 bits java? actually i uninstalled both java and R and reinstall both, but is not working, i will try the openxlsx and told u, tank u for reading

Comment: Like @Gregor, I recommend {readxl} to read and {writexl} to write Excel files as they do not require Java.