# Convert Excel file to csv via R without having Microsoft excel on my computer?

Tags: r, csv, excel-online

I'm using R packages that require input files, but I don't have Microsoft Excel on my computer. Is there a way I can add an input file through Microsoft online or turn a read-only Excel file into a usable csv file?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to import? Is it an `xsl` or `xslx` file? Have you tried the `readxl` package? That does not require you to have office installed. It would be better if the file were just a `csv` file because that's just a plain text file that anyone can read. In Excel, you can "save as" a csv file. You don't need excel to read `csv` files

Comment: Basically I'm given a flashdrive with an xslx file and which needs to be the input file for this R file. Normally, I would save the xslx file as a cvs file and then I say something like read.csv("filename", header = TRUE, sep = ",") and go from there, but the computer I'm working on doesn't have excel so I can't resave the file. Is there a way to forego that step?

Comment: There are several packages available to read Excel files.  `readxl` is a popular one.  This answer lists other options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script